# How to add labels within a view programmatically

Tags: swift, user-interface, uiview, autolayout

I'm experimenting with layout anchors, and I'm trying to replicate the following illustration: basically an outer view with an inner view. The inner view is anchored with constants to the outer view's bottom anchor and the leading anchor. This much is done.

However, I would then like to place a label inside the inner view, and be able to center the label/s in that view. Is this possible?

Ideally I could then go an alter the constants of the view later on, and the labels would still be correctly positioned.

[image]

Just some pointers in the right direction would be useful.

Comment: This is what I hate about Stack Overflow - people asking basic questions that are covered in every basic book or course. Or in zillion Stack Overflow Q&As.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the view.

```
let innerView = UIView()
```

Then the labels.

```
let label1 = UILabel()
let label2 = UILabel()
```

Place the inner view inside the main view

```
view.addSubview(innerView)
```

After you add the innerView to the view.
You can provide a position and size to the inner view.

```
innerView.frame = CGRect(x: (self.view.frame.size.width) - (self.view.frame.size.width) + 10, y: (self.view.frame.size.height) - (self.view.frame.size.height) - 150, width: 500, height: 500)
```

Then add in the labels into the inner view

```
innerView.addSubview(label1)
innerView.addSubview(label2)
```

Then you can apply constraints to the labels inside the inner view and give it size

```
label1.frame = CGRect(x:100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 20)
label2.frame = CGRect(x:100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick pointer is to use `UIStackView` with

```
stack.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
```

> distribution = fill
>
> alignment = center
>
> axis  = vertical

You may also need to set lbl's alignment = center